# Why can't I retrieve data from event_member table? Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

For some reason my code doesn't work, and I'm not sure why. This format works well with other tables but when I try to retrieve the event id from the event_member table it's not returning anything. Is there anything I'm doing wrong. I know for a fact I am attending several events so it would have to return them.

```
require_once 'facebook.php';    //Facebook class

$Facebook = new Facebook($config);                  //Initialize Facebook
$fb = $Facebook->getUser();                             //Get the user

//Authorize the user
if ($fb)
{
    try 
    {
        $user = $Facebook->api('/me');
    } 
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
    {
        echo "There was an unexpected error. Please contact us.";
        $fb = null;
    }
}

try
{
    $fql = "SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me()";
    $param = array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $fql, 'callback' => '');

    $result = $Facebook->api($param);

    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        echo $row["eid"] . "<br/>";
    }
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
{
  echo $e;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To read the event_member table you need: the **user_events** permission for non-public events or to see all events a user is attending

*Source:* https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/

---

[How to ask for permissions in PHP:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/)

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```